# How can I search and replace in multiple Word files?

Tags: microsoft-word, find-and-replace

I am looking for a way to do search and replace in many Word (.doc) files (for the purpose of automation of the process).

The software I found so far only allows me to search, but not replace.

How can I do that with Word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try [VBA Find & Replace](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:o-iR-x4B-oMJ:https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/vba_find_and_replace.html+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=au&client=firefox-b-d) (cached link).

> VBA Find and Replace© provides a method for finding and replacing text anywhere in a document (or collection of documents) using single user defined "find" and "replace" variable pairs, or a user defined list of "find" and "replace" pairs. It also provides a method to find text and replace found text with a user defined "AutoText" or "Building Block" entry.

Comment: This looks just like what I wanted - You rock!

Comment: Which files does this plugin search over? I cannot find a possibility to specify a starting directory. Does it use all open files only? And how do I just search without replacing?

Comment: @gentlesea does 'Process Files in Batch Folder' setting not help?

Comment: There's an extra period on the end of that URL – I'd remove it but StackOverflow is designed incorrectly and prevents that: http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/VBA_Find_And_Replace.htm

Comment: @ChrisAdams: thanks buddy, it's fixed now. It didn't let you suggest an edit?

Comment: @jay: sadly it requires a minimum of 6 characters to be changed and I didn't see anything else obvious

Comment: the provided link is now broken... may I know how to do the VBA Find and Replace© ?

Comment: @p._phidot_ Updated link from Google cache

Comment: thank you, really appreciate it. ( :

Answer (score 0):

For a purpose of executing multiple normal and wildcard-based replacements in multiple MS Word files located in multiple folders under given root folder, I have created following VBA macro. In order to use it, you have change content of following variables (constants):

- **rootPath**: root folder under which are located folders containing Word documents.
- **findTextsWild** and **replaceTextsWild**: array of wildcard-based find and replace expressions.
- **findTexts** and **replaceTexts**: array of normal find and replace expressions.

May be you will find it usefull :-)

```
Sub GlobalTextReplacement()
' Root under which all manuals are stored
Dim rootPath As String
rootPath = "c:\Data\Manuals\"

' Find and replace text for wildcard replacement. Performed first.
Dim findTextsWild() As Variant, replaceTextsWild() As Variant
findTextsWild = Array("[ ]{2;}", "[cC]onfiguration[/ ]@[pP]olicy [rR]epository", "[sS]ervlet[- ]@[fF]ilter")
replaceTextsWild = Array(" ", "Configuration/Policy Repository", "Servlet-Filter")

' Find and replace text for normal case insensitive replacement. Performed second.
Dim findTexts() As Variant, replaceTexts() As Variant
findTexts = Array("DirX Access", "Policy Repository", "User Repository", "Servlet", "servletfilter", "SAML assertion", "DirX Access Server", "DirX Access Manager", "Deployment Manager", "Policy Manager", "Client SDK", "^p ", " ^p")
replaceTexts = Array("DirX Access", "Policy Repository", "User Repository", "Servlet", "Servlet-Filter", "SAML assertion", "DirX Access Server", "DirX Access Manager", "Deployment Manager", "Policy Manager", "Client SDK", "^p", "^p")

' Main code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim dirNames(20) As String
Dim dirNamesCount As Integer
dirNamesCount = 0

Dim dirName As String
dirName = Dir$(rootPath & "*", vbDirectory)
Do Until LenB(dirName) = 0
    Dim dirPath As String
    dirPath = rootPath & dirName
    If ((GetAttr(dirPath) And vbDirectory) = vbDirectory) And (dirName <> ".") And (dirName <> "..") Then
        dirNamesCount = dirNamesCount + 1
        dirNames(dirNamesCount) = dirPath & "\"
    End If
    dirName = Dir$
Loop

Do While dirNamesCount > 0
    Dim fileName As String
    dirName = dirNames(dirNamesCount)
    dirNamesCount = dirNamesCount - 1
    fileName = Dir$(dirName & "*.doc", vbDirectory)
    Do Until LenB(fileName) = 0
        Dim filePath As String
        filePath = dirName & fileName
        fileName = Dir$

        Dim document As document
        Set document = Documents.Open(filePath)
        document.TrackRevisions = True

        document.Select

        Dim i As Integer, maxIndex As Integer
        maxIndex = UBound(findTextsWild)
        For i = LBound(findTextsWild) To maxIndex
            With Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Text = findTextsWild(i)
                .Replacement.Text = replaceTextsWild(i)
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
                    Wrap:=wdFindContinue, MatchWildcards:=True
            End With
        Next

        maxIndex = UBound(findTexts)
        For i = LBound(findTexts) To maxIndex
            With Selection.Find
                .ClearFormatting
                .Replacement.ClearFormatting
                .Text = findTexts(i)
                .Replacement.Text = replaceTexts(i)
                .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True, _
                    Wrap:=wdFindContinue, MatchCase:=False, MatchWildcards:=False
            End With
        Next

        document.Save
        document.Close
    Loop
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Can't it be done in Microsoft Word itself?

Its in your Edit menu (Word 2003) or Home tab/Editing section (Word 2007)

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA012303921033.aspx

Comment: Just saw your comment on tombull89's post.

For word 2003, you can follow these instructions: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HP051894331033.aspx

Comment: both links are dead now

Answer (score -1):

If you don't own Microsoft Word and are looking for a free alternative which will help you, try [OpenOffice.org](http://www.openoffice.org).

I don't think this will help you if you're looking for a way to automate this process.

Answer (score -1):

Notepad++ Is able to do this using "Find in Files"

Comment: Keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Shift+F

Comment: Notepad++ can open Microsoft Word documents?

Comment: This MAY work iff the string match and replacement string are not special characters because Word 2007+ documents are actually XML files by nature. But I said it may. Have you cared to test this before posting as an answer.

Answer (score -2):

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BatchReplaceAll()
    Dim FirstLoop As Boolean
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim PathToUse As String
    Dim myDoc As Document
    Dim Response As Long

    PathToUse = ActiveDocument.Path
    On Error Resume Next
    Documents.Close SaveChanges:=wdPromptToSaveChanges
    FirstLoop = True
    myFile = Dir$(PathToUse & "\*.doc*")

    While myFile <> ""
        Set myDoc = Documents.Open(PathToUse & "\" & myFile)
        If FirstLoop Then
            Application.Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace).Show
            FirstLoop = False

            Response = MsgBox("Do you want to process the rest of the files in this folder", vbYesNo)
            If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub
        Else
            With Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)
                .ReplaceAll = 1
                .Execute
            End With
        End If
        myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges
        myFile = Dir$()
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: What is this block of code, what does it do, and how can it help solve this problem?