# Find and Replace text in multiple Word files

Tags: microsoft-word

I am looking for a way to search and replace text in multiple Word files. (.doc, .docx, .dotx)

Currently I got over 2k word files with the following variable in my footer, called (.MEFZ)

I need the .MEFZ replaced by a multilined text, sort of looking like this:

Firemenanschrift....................................................................................Bankverbindung
Institutionskennzeichen: xxxxxxxx............................................................Textblabla

Is it possible to get this done by a PowerShell Script or any other automated process?

Thanks in advance and greetings from Germany :)

Comment: There are 2 old questions that cover this topic. http://superuser.com/questions/553340/multiple-find-and-replace-in-a-word-document?rq=1 and this http://superuser.com/questions/140262/how-can-i-search-and-replace-in-multiple-word-files?rq=1 with a bunch of dead links.